Why feeding the same sample N times reduces resampler latency?
I am re-implementing the PlayStation reverb algorithm in C#.
Here's how it works:

44100 Hz input gets resampled to 22050 Hz for reverb (it only supports that rate)
reverb is applied, resampled back to 44100 Hz, output to speakers

So, after writing the resampler and DRY-ing the code, I mistakenly fed it twice the samples and noticed that it actually reduced the latency of the resampler!
Legend:

source signal is in red color
output signal is in blue color
horizontal axis is in samples
@ <X, Y> is the line scaling

Initial algorithm:
(inputs are sinusoids at 220.5 Hz and 441 Hz respectively)

After accidentally queuing the same sample(s) N times:
(shown to the max. possible)

I then rendered 4K plots (not shown) to try figure how far I could crank it up:

22 to 44 accepts queuing 1, 2, 5 or 10 times the same sample
44 to 22 accepts queuing 1 to 10 times the same samples

Beyond that, either it doesn't reduce latency or output happens before input in time, which I suppose is wrong somehow...
Code for one resampler: (others are similar)
(discards N old samples, adds N new samples at end of buffer)
public abstract class Resampler<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public abstract void Process(Span<T> source, Span<T> target);

    protected static void Enqueue(Span<T> source, T[] target, int offset, int length)
    {
        target.AsSpan(length).CopyTo(target.AsSpan());

        source.Slice(offset, length).CopyTo(target.AsSpan(Index.FromEnd(length)));
    }
}

public sealed class ResamplerFloat4422 : Resampler<float>
{
    public ResamplerFloat4422()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Taps.Length; i++)
        {
            Taps[i] /= 16384.0f;
        }
    }

    private float[] Data { get; } = new float[40];

    private float[] Taps { get; } =
    {
        -1, 2, -10, 35, -103, 266, -616, 1332, -2960, 10246, 10246, -2960, 1332, -616, 266, -103, 35, -10, 2, -1
    };

    public override void Process(Span<float> source, Span<float> target)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(source.Length / 2, target.Length);

        var len = source.Length;
        var src = 0;
        var tgt = 0;

        for (; src < len; src += 2, tgt += 1)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
            {
                Enqueue(source, Data, src, 2);
            }

            var output = Data[19];

            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                output += Taps[i] * Data[i * 2];
            }

            target[tgt] = Math.Clamp(output * 0.5f, -1.0f, +1.0f);
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(source.Length, src);
        Assert.AreEqual(target.Length, tgt);
    }
}

Questions:
Why does feeding the same sample(s) N times reduces latency?
Should this accidental discovery be used or avoided? If no, why?

The code looks like they time align the output with the center tap of the lowpass filter, so this per se should not add any latency. This is probably related to the buffering scheme that feeds and the function, not the function itself. The filter itself has an inherent latency of 19 samples (at the input rate) but as long as that's smaller than the block size, then this shouldn't impact the overall latency at all.  Do you know that the block sizes are for your examples?

@Hilmar The code in PSX emulators feed 1/2 samples depending 22/44 or 44/22 and output 1/2 samples. Above, I feed 200/400 samples as seen on X axis. Had to write such cache logic as I will use it as an effect where callee receives ~1024 samples to process. What I don't get is, why repeating last sample(s) N times reduces latency? Doesn't resampling need real history like a regular filter does? It's all witchcraft for me right now...

@Hilmar Forgot to mention the most important thing, you said the filter has a latency; that is totally expected due to how it works. But how come an XYZ process is able to overcome the latency (or maybe just in appearance)? I thought latency was an inherent thing and impossible to get around it, i.e. it looks like magic and sounds too good be true. But I don't know at all what's currently happening, hence the question!

Anyone has any idea?

It's not real. True latency can only get larger. The filter code looks fine whatever happens, happens in the surrounding code or something is wrong with your test rig. Can't tell without seeing the whole thing. I suggest testing this with a single impulse you can you single step and see what happens.
